# Electron nsis-web, how to change artifacts names

Tags: electron, nsis, electron-builder, electron-updater

How to change artifacts name, for nsis-web with autoupdater?
By default archives for web installer named like {appName}{version}-{arch}.{ext}

```
• building embedded block map  file=dist/nsis-web/app-1.0.0-ia32.nsis.7z
• building embedded block map  file=dist/nsis-web/app-1.0.0-x64.nsis.7z
```

How i can remove versioning from here?

It should be like this

```
• building embedded block map  file=dist/nsis-web/app-ia32.nsis.7z
• building embedded block map  file=dist/nsis-web/app-x64.nsis.7z
```

Answer (score 0):

according to [electron-build nsis build docs](https://www.electron.build/configuration/nsis) , you can define the application name

> artifactName String - The artifact file name template. Defaults to `${productName} Setup ${version}.${ext}`

you can add following [macros](https://www.electron.build/file-patterns#file-macros) listed here

> `${arch}` — expanded to ia32, x64. If no arch, macro will be removed
>   from your pattern with leading space, - and _ (so, you don’t need to
>   worry and can reuse pattern).
>
> `${os}` — expanded to mac, linux or win
>   according to target platform. 
>   `${platform}` — expanded to darwin, linux or win32 according to Node.js process.platform property.
>
> `${name}` – package.json name.
>
> `${productName}` — Sanitized product name.
>
> `${version}`
>
> `${channel}` — detected prerelease component from version (e.g. beta).
>
> `${env.ENV_NAME}` — any environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem,
in short, UNFORTUNATELY YOU CAN'T.

I went to look at the code of electron-builder:

```
 const archiveFile = path.join(this.outDir, `${packager.appInfo.sanitizedName}-${packager.appInfo.version}-${Arch[arch]}.nsis.${format}`)   
... [some code]...

    // [THE NEXT CODE IS THE ONE ARCHIVING YOUR NSIS]
    if (isBuildDifferentialAware && this.isWebInstaller) {
      const data = await appendBlockmap(archiveFile)

... [more code]...
```

https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/blob/040327814e8299340c4755d3ad05958e6925aab1/packages/app-builder-lib/src/targets/nsis/NsisTarget.ts#L19

this is the code that archive the webNsis,you can see that it uses `const archiveFile` as a parameter for `appendBlockmap()`, but you can't set the value of this const and it is hard coded

`artifactName` controls only the `.exe` file name, not the `nsis.7z` constant.